# How can I make a ListView object in Tile View select the entire tile rather than just a mask

Tags: c#, listview

I currently have a listview set to tile view.

[image]

When I select it it only creates a mask like selection over the tile.

[image]

I want to have the entire tile highlighted to give it a button effect.

[image]

Is there any way to do this with a stock ListView or will I need to create my own control and do some subclassing?

Comment: Use something like this `e.DrawBackground();
            if (e.Item.Selected) e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.AliceBlue, e.Bounds);
            Image img = listView1.LargeImageList.Images[e.ItemIndex];
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, e.Bounds.Location);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.Text, e.Item.Font, Brushes.Black, 
                e.Bounds.Left + img.Width + 2, e.Bounds.Top + e.Bounds.Height / 2);` in the `DrawItem` event

Answer (score -2):

**It is not possible.**
You may have to create your own control, or use a Rectangle to give the impression you want. ListBox control doesn't give this possiblity yet...

Comment: Is there any other control that will do something similar to what I'm after?

Comment: Owner-drawing will do it. Also: He asks not about ListBox but about ListView.